# Get number field in sitecore index

Tags: webforms, sitecore

I'd like to know how do you guys get a value from a number field through index search.

I'm using WebForms for my project currently I have this model

```
[IndexField("SomeNumber")]
int SomeNumber { get; set; }
```

and obviously a number field named "SomeNumber" in my sitecore item. But the thing is I only get 0 value for SomeNumber when I input a number on the field and a null when not. Note that I'm getting right values for my string fields so I'm not sure why the number field doesn't work right.

Thanks

Comment: If `SomeNumber` is using `int` type, it's not possible that it's null. Do you use lucene or solr? Is your field marked as STORED in your index configuration?

Comment: My bad yeah it's not null. I'm using solr

Comment: Open `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`. Check `defaultSolrIndexConfiguration` if `indexAllFields` property is set to `true`. If yes, it means that the field IS stored in SOLR. If not, make sure it's added to `IncludeField` list. If it still is not retrieved from Solr properly, check if you don't have any type it your field name (like missing space or something). Remember that you don't need to add any suffixes (like `_t`) to the `IndexField` attribute. And of course, check in Solr admin if the field is stored there.

Comment: I looked at the config and the indexAllFields is true. I tried converting the search result into a json object and I saw a value "rating_t" with the right value that I'm looking for. Do you know what _t means?

Comment: It means that the value is stored as string, not as a number. Make sure that the field is using `Number` field type  in Sitecore and rebuild the index. Or if this is not an option, change your property to `string` type and create getter that will parse it for you.